# Append something to the label item using enumitem?

Tags: lists, enumitem, description

Is there some easy way to append some code (or text) to appear directly after the label item, but before the text, in a description list using the `enumitem` package?

Here's an example below to show what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[description]{%
   %appendtolabel=.,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[First] bla bla blaa.
  \item[Second] bla bla blaa.
  \item[Third] bla bla blaa.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

From this I would like to get:

```
First. bla bla blaa.
Second. bla bla blaa.
Third. bla bla blaa.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After carefully reading the documentation of `enumitem`, I realized that you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% Typeset descriptions
\newcommand{\appendDot}[1]{#1.}
\setlist[description]{%
  font=\appendDot,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[First] bla bla blaa.
  \item[Second] bla bla blaa.
  \item[Third] bla bla blaa.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```