# Add symbol after the lable of every description item

Tags: enumitem, description

I often use the `description` environment and I want to separate the label from the text not only by whitespace, but also by a small circle.
I'm using the `enumitem` package to customize the `description` env., but I did not find a way of adding text after the label.

Default look:

```
Item  text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
```

What I want:

```
Item ○ text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
    text text text text text text text
```

I already tried the following:

```tex
\setlist[description]{labelsep={\circ}}
```

and

```tex
\setlist[description]{%
    before={\changeitem},
    after={\renewcommand\item\olditem},
}
\newcommand{\changeitem}{%
    \let\olditem\item
    \renewcommand\item[1]{\olditem (##1) \circ }
}
```

But both examples did not achieve the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [Append something to the label item using enumitem?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170736):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\addcircle}[1]{#1 $\circ$}
    \setlist[description]{%
        font=\addcircle}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item [item1]  a first item
    \item [item2] a second item
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot!